# Solo se elimina el primer dato de una tabla con MySql, Php y Js

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, tablas

Estoy intentando eliminar datos de una tabla MySql con js y php. El problema es que solo funciona con el primer dato, siempre que intento en el resto de los datos la pagina se recarga y no realiza la funcion del js.
PHP Y HTML usado para la tabla:

```
<tbody id="contenido">
                    <?php
                    $consulta = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios INNER JOIN roles ON usuarios.usu_rol = roles.rol_id");
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="id" style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['usu_nom'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['usu_ape'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['usu_mail'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['rol_nom'] ?></td>

                            <?php if ($_SESSION['rol_nom'] === "Administrador") { ?>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editar<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>">Editar</button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalborrar<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>">Eliminar</button>
                                </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- Modal Eliminar -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalborrar<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?></h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <form method="POST" id="formeliminar">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>" name="id">
                                            <p>Esta seguro que dedea eliminar a <?php echo $row['usu_nom'] . " " . $row['usu_ape'] ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success">Eliminar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                <?php }
                        } ?>

                </tbody>
```

Con el while muestro todos los datos de latabla y obtengo la id del dato seleccionado y los muestra en el modal correctamente.
El Js lo cambie por una alerta como prueba pero funciona de la misma manera, cuando le doy a cualquier dato que no sea el primero en la tabla se recarga la pagina

```
var formeliminar = document.getElementById("formeliminar");
formeliminar.addEventListener("submit", eliminar);

function eliminar(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  alert("hola");
}
```

Las primeras lineas son para tomar el formulario y ejecutar la funcion al enviarlo

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, así podrás comunicar entre cliente y servidor de forma limpia, sin necesidad de modales, ni de recargas de página ni mezcla entre los contextos. Los modales datan de los año 90, con el boom de Windows, hoy día, un modal sólo serviría para un diálogo que debe ser obligatorio, como una confirmación o algo así ... y quizá ni eso, porque tú puedes bloquear/desbloquear botones de acción en la misma interfaz mediante la escucha de eventos y demás. En fin, hoy día puedes prescindir totalmente de los modales y de su pésima exp. de usuario

Comment: @A.Cedano coincido contigo, pero si el OP está iniciando su aprendizaje o está retocando código escrito hace tiempo, no está de más orientarlo un poco con lo que está usando. Recuerdo que en algún momento me hiciste una observación similar con los modales y lo asimilé de la mejor manera, tanto así que en proyectos recientes ya no los uso. Sin embargo debo darle mantenimiento a proyectos antiguos _(próximos a salir de producción)_ y es más fácil modificar los modales que refactorizar todo el proyecto, _al menos hasta que se tengan cambios considerables que justifiquen la refactorización_.

Comment: Hola, aun estoy empezando en esto sobre todo en js, con php ya llevo un tiempo experimentando cosas. Uso los modales de bootstrap mas que todo por que me parcen esteticos.

Comment: @DjCrazy entiendo tu punto, yo hago estos señalamientos con la intención de que OP conozca otras posibilidades y las pueda aplicar en un futuro, como de hecho ha sido tu caso según comentas. Entiendo que en contextos de ejercicio y demás no queda otra que ceñirse a lo que se ha pedido. Pero para alguien que empieza no tendría ningún reparo en animarle a aprender a usar Ajax o la API Fetch (la curva de aprendizaje básica no pasará de un par de días, porque son herramientas muy fáciles) y OP empezará a programar con las ideas un poco claras de lo que es el contexto del cliente y el del ...

Comment: ... servidor. Viendo preguntas aquí, ese concepto no está para nada claro en muchos OP y eso es fuente de mucho código mal escrito y con una experiencia de usuario pésima. Con los modales pasa lo mismo, la gente los usa a veces porque *son bonitos*. Los modales eran *bonitos* en los 90, porque mucha gente salió de la consola, pero en 2022 los modales son malos en muchos casos, porque te obligan a estar cambiando de interfaz, cuando puedes tener todo integrado, como un escritorio de trabajo, sin tener que estar abriendo/cerrando gavetas por aquí y por allá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifico varios detalles en tu código.

1. Los modales no deben estar dentro del ciclo `while` ya que estarías creando uno por cada iteración y no es correcto.
2. Cuando le pasas este `id` al modal `id="modalborrar<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>"`, realmente estás asociando el ultimo `id` de la iteración.

Posibles soluciones:

1. Crea el modal fuera del ciclo y asígnale un `id` único, por ejemplo `id="modalborrar"`
2. El botón para abrir el modal, quedaría con el `data-bs-target="#modalborrar"`
3. A este mismo botón, le pasas un evento `onclick="asignarUsuario(".<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>.")"`
4. En `JS` ejecutas una función que recibe como parámetro el `id` del usuario y se lo asigna al `input` correspondiente `<input value="" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario">`

Quedando algo así:

```
//En el ciclo while
//Código previo
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalborrar" onclick="asignarUsuario(".<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>.")">Eliminar</button>
</td>
//...

//En el modal, fuera del ciclo...
//Código previo
<div class="modal fade" id="modalborrar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
//...
<input type="hidden" value="" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario">
//...

//Y en el JS
function asignarUsuario(idUsuario) {
  document.getElementById("idUsuario").setAttribute("value", idUsuario);
}
```

Prueba y comenta.

Comment: Hola, muchisimas gracias. Me funciono correctamente, ahora se ejecuta la funcion con todos los datos. De verdad te lo agradezco mucho estuve varios dias intentando saber que pasaba. una pregunta mas, solo por curiosidad ¿Sabes por que se recargaba la pagina?

Comment: Si te soy franco, no sé porque razón lo hacía ya que desconozco tu entorno de desarrollo. Asumo que se ejecutaba el evento `submit` antes de hacer cualquier otra acción. Por otro lado, si la respuesta fue útil, te sugiero marcarla como tal con los controles que aparecen a la izquierda de la misma. El check indica que solucionó tu pregunta y el upvote indica que fue útil. De este modo ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad. Por último, mi respuesta está basada en tu necesidad, cuando adquieras un poco más de experiencia te sugiero seguir las recomendaciones de @a.cedano en su comentario.

Comment: Gracias, y lo tendre en cuenta. Y quiero hacerte otra pregunta ¿Como puedo mostrar los datos del usuario como lo hacia antes? Por ejemplo cuando el modal estaba en el while usaba el mismo `$row` para mostrar un mensaje con el nombre del usuario que se va a borrar.

Comment: Puedes concatenar en una variable `$nombre = $row['usu_nom'] . " " . $row['usu_ape'];` y pasarla como segundo parámetro a la función. Ojo, que al ser un `string` debes pasarlo entre comillas simples, así: `onclick="asignarUsuario(".<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>.", '".<?php echo $nombre ?>."')"`. Luego, puedes hacer el mismo proceso como le asignaste el `value` al `input` pero ahora al `HTML` del elemento `<p>` o a un `<span>` que tenga un `id` único. Depende de cómo lo quieras manejar.

Comment: Ahí es donde se va complicando el uso de los modales, por eso es importante que busques info de `ajax` y `fetch`. Si tienes preguntas adicionales, te recomiendo abrir una pregunta nueva en lugar de extender los comentarios de esta. Te sugiero hacer el recorrido (está en el footer) para que conozcas un poco más la comunidad y de paso ganas nuevas medallas.